# Typescript generics with Class does not work or what i am doing wrong?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
class Some<AttributeType = {
    bar: string
}> {
    foo(attrs: AttributeType) {
        if (attrs.bar) {
            console.log(attrs.bar)
        }
    }
}
```

ts failed with error

```
Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'AttributeType'.
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEDKB7AtgUwDwEEAu2BOAlgEYCu2qAKgJ4AOqsAvLAN7CzuxER4BcsU+AgDsA5sAC+APhZsOAM0SIAFBFx4ofHINLlqdAJQyOx2ATmwVaqADoueQ6xNPYIREKiIwqa2EQjL+DZ2+rJO4qGw4eFAA

Answer (score 2):

Use `extends` keyword instead of `=`:

```
class Some<AttributeType extends {  bar: string  }>
```

More here ([TypeScript generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)).

By using the `=` syntax you provided a default generic parameter and you can use your class in a following way:

```
let x: Some;
```

Which would be impossible if you removed it. What you need is to define a constraint which will allow the compiler to infer that your generic type always contains `bar` field.